# Solving Dirichlet problem by means of potential theory

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, convolution, potential-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded smooth domain and consider the Dirichlet problem with $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ $$\tag{1}-\Delta u=f$$

Is there a way to solve this problem by using potential theory, i.e. if $\Gamma $ is a fundamental solution of $-\Delta$, is it possible to give a precise meaning for the expression $\Gamma\star f=v$ and then prove that $v$ is a weak solution of $(1)$?

Update: Let me simplify things a little bit. Suppose that $f\in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $f$ is supported in $\Omega$, i.e. $f$ is a suported distribution.

$f$ being a supported distribution, we have that $f\star\varphi (x)=\langle f, \varphi(x+\cdot)\rangle$ belongs to $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for all $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Hence, it makes sense to define $f\star\Gamma$ (note that in this case $f\star\Gamma$ solves $(1)$) as distribution acting like this $$\langle f\star\Gamma,\varphi\rangle=\langle\Gamma,f\star\varphi(x)\rangle$$

Can I conclude that $f\star\Gamma\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Thank you

Comment: Hmmm...interesting, intuitively this is not good. $f$ can be very singular and the convolution might not raise the regularity to $H^1$ (just my hunch). If only we can find somehow an $L^2$-"representation" of $f\in H^{-1}$, can we?

Comment: In fact @ShuhaoCao, I was thinking in $f\in H^{-1}\setminus L^2$. Do you know any method to raise "regularity" of distributions? I mean, "any" distribtuion.

Comment: Dear @ShuhaoCao, I have changed the question a little bit, please take a look on it.

Comment: I think you should be able to. From the standard theory Hilbert space theory, there is a unique solution $u \in H^1$ to the equation (1) for fixed boundary conditions, which is usually called the solution or Green's operator. That operator happens to coincide with convolution with the Green's function for all suitable functions. That basically means that it should work for distributions as well.

Comment: That is what I think too @RayYang, but I was unable to prove it. It seems that the calculations must be easy, but when I try to do it, I get nowhere... That the convolution is a solution I alread find it on some books, but the regularity I was unable to find it and I could not prove it also.